# Lost Oracle database after windows installation on same directory

Tags: database, oracle, backup, database-backups, recovery

I have installed new Windows on my laptop and  unfortunately forgot to `backup` my database from `Oracle` that was installed on same directory as windows.
Can someone please help me out to get my database back as it was very important and wasn't backed up?

Advance Thanks for valuable support!

Comment: Most likely you will never forget again to make a backup...

Comment: Why on earth do you store the database in the windows folder?

Comment: haha "THERE ARE NO FAILURES ONLY LESSONS LEARNED" ;)